# Where is the iptables MARK location in TCP package?

Tags: networking, iptables, tcp, wireshark

In my CentOS7 Server, I emptied all the iptables rules, and then add below rule:

```
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT  
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
    
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1  
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
```

I can check it:

```
[root@localhost go-tproxy]# iptables -n -L  -t mangle
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DIVERT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            socket
    
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
    
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
    
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
    
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
    
Chain DIVERT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MARK       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MARK set 0x1
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

and my iptables service in my Server is active.

You see the `MARK set 0x1` tag in rules,
and then I use`ping www.demo.com`and `curl  -vo 1 'https://google.com' to test the data. and I capture the packages by wireshark, you can check:
https://github.com/moonshineBoy/pastebin_files

I didn't find the location of the MARK set 0x1 in `capture-https.pcapng`,  please tell me where is the MARK location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere. Marks only exist internally within the kernel's network stack – they can be matched by other iptables rules, policy routing rules, tc filters – but are not transmitted over the network.

(Packet marks are stored in the `skb->mark` field; connection marks are stored in the conntrack system.)

Comment: then how can kernel identify the actual packet? so the mark in kernel can correspond the actual packet.

Comment: The kernel doesn't simply pass around raw packets – it keeps internal metadata attached to them; a larger structure (in Linux's case that's the [`struct sk_buff`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L751)) with fields indicating the packet mark, received interface, time when it was received, _lots_ of other internal parameters, and only at the end there's a field containing the actual packet data.